# How do I make it so after i declare a tag in a text-field: the text overlays said tag and continues on letting me type?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

[image] So i want the text to write over the declared tag made by the user. I want it to overlap/cover it. I thought about making div appear in javascript when the user finishes their tag the characters "var mytagname;" along the semicolon which establishes the end of tag name. so everything inside their then is transferred to a javascript div and is popped off from the input field. that same value is returned to the field and popped from the background so the user can delete/edit the tag.  of course along some hacky css. but I don't know if I'm making this way to complicated or if it will work. im still familiarizing myself with the corral of javascript dom

ive tried googling to see if there any problems or pieces of the problem on the internet but their is none.

I wanted to try my solution my maybe my thinking is over complicating the solution.

```
code::                                 
       

     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .blurred-text {
      filter: blur(1.5px); /* Apply the blur effect */
    }

    div#main {
      /*position: absolute;
      z-index: 50;*/

      /*display: none;*/
      color: transparent;
      caret-color: black; /* Add the caret-color property to set the text cursor color */
    }

    div#main::selection {
      color: transparent;
      background: transparent;
    }

    div#main {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 50;
    }

    div#output {
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    div#main, div#output {
      outline: none;

      min-width: 3cm;
      min-height: 1cm;

      max-width: 90vw;
      max-height: 90vh;

      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div contenteditable="true" id="main">
    </div>

    <div contenteditable="false" id="output">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let main = document.querySelector('div#main');
    let outp = document.querySelector('div#output');

    // Colors to replace[[]] this code was from a stackoverflow post that had part of my solution for a problem a faced and i added it to my solution, im going to delete it soon.
    const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'magenta', 'purple', 'black', 'white', 'grey', 'gray', 'cyan', 'orange', 'crimson', 'salmon', 'pink', 'violet', 'turquoise', 'firebrick', 'gainsboro', 'honeydew', 'ivory', 'indigo', 'lavender', 'lime', 'linen', 'maroon'];
    const keywords = {
      cool: 2,
      'black cat': 8,
      happy: 1,
      var: 2 // Add 'var' keyword with index 2 for blue color
    };

    // When user enters something, style it
    main.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      outp.innerText = this.innerText;
        
      // Apply blur to text after 'var' until ';'
      const varIndex = outp.innerText.indexOf('var');
      const semicolonIndex = outp.innerText.indexOf(';');
      if (varIndex !== -1 && semicolonIndex !== -1 && semicolonIndex > varIndex) {
        const blurredVarText = `<span class="blurred-text">${outp.innerText.substring(varIndex, semicolonIndex + 1)}</span>`; // Wrap variable text in a span with blurred class
        outp.innerHTML = outp.innerText.substring(0, varIndex) + blurredVarText + outp.innerText.substring(semicolonIndex + 1);
      } else {
        outp.innerHTML = outp.innerText; // Reset output HTML if semicolon is not found
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(keywords).length; i++) {
        const keywords_ = Object.keys(keywords);
        const keyword = keywords_[i];
        const color = colors[keywords[keyword]];

        outp.innerHTML = outp.innerHTML.replaceAll(new RegExp('(' + keyword + ')', 'gi'), '<span style="color: ' + color + ';">$1</span>');
      }
    });

    // Style initial values
    main.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    main.addEventListener('click', outp.focus);

    outp.style.top  = main.offsetTop .toString() + 'px';
    outp.style.left = main.offsetLeft.toString() + 'px';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```